# Not able to open DirectX 11 App (Universal Windows) template in VS2017 - HResult 0x80042003

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directx

Question1: Do you **NEED** to use Windows 10 to use DirectX 11 app programming?

Explanation: I searched for the right tools to install everything needed to use DirectX 11 app. I would like to use it for some 2D game i have in mind. After everything installed, and restarted VS2017, I looked for the app in the VS C++ browser, found it, but when I give it a name and press "OK", it first asks me which minimum platform I want to use.

Thats the first thing I don't understand because only Windows 10 is available. But when I click one and want to go further, HResult 0x80042003 is thrown.

Looked around for it on the internet, no much information is given. The 1 thing I made from all the explanations is you may need windows 10 installed. I work on windows 7.

If anyone could help me, thanks.
If you need some more information, ask!

New on the forum and yes, checked the forum already, found some information, but wasn't meant to me I think.

Greetings,

Stijn

Comment: Universal apps are not supported in Windows 7

Comment: Ok, thanks. Going to look for windows 10

Comment: Windows 10 is only required for Universal applications, DirectX 11 can be used on Windows 7 (or even on Windows Vista) from a regular desktop application.